# Which version of Eclipse to use with Android

Tags: android, eclipse, version

I'm an old developer (Active since the Z80 days) starting fresh with Android.

1. The Android Developers page recommends installing Eclipse before installing the Android SDK.
2. It also states "There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice."
3. The Eclipse download page seems to offer 11 different flavors of the package. None mention Android and all seem to be the Version 3.6 that the Android Developers pages recommends avoiding. - What does one do?

Comments welcome
Joe Cullity

Comment: I hope to get a response to this. Even I'm new to android,but confused with which version of eclipse to download.The new ADT doesn't support eclipse 3.5 http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html ..could you please check to see if this one is good enough to download -- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2 .. thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get [version 3.5 of Eclipse for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/galileosr2) (you can reach this page via the "Older versions" link on the main download page). One of the problems I had with 3.6 was that autocomplete would freeze up for seconds at a time, trying to look up Android source. Until they fix that, 3.5 is better.

Once you've installed Eclipse, then you can follow [the instructions to install the Android plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing).

Comment: Yes, don't use 3.6 yet. Had the same experience with suggest box freezing.

Comment: :( I've had that same issue with 3.5...wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @kcoppock, Were you using 3.6 to begin with? Some people report that downgrading to 3.5 didn't help unless they started a new workspace.

Comment: Ah, that could be it, I did start with 3.6. I'll have to try the new workspace and see if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The "Older versions" phrase really helped, I was looking at the page for 5 minuets and couldn't find it, so I tried [SEARCH - "Older versions"] and it popped right up. - Joe

Comment: @Nick the new ADT doesn't support eclipse 3.5 http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html ..could you please check to see if this one is good enough to download -- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2 .. thank you :)

Comment: Nope - just try the latest Eclipse now, it might work fine. A lot changes in a year.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm running is Eclipse Galileo 3.5.0 and works great for me.

You want to download the "flavor" labeled *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* from eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

I got MotoDev which is a complete Eclipse install with the Android SDK.  It has emulators for all Moto phones.  Perferct start in my opinion.  Plus it's all Eclipse so you can all all the other options you want.

If you are interested download here:
http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/download/

have fun, I am.